# Importing results of FEM analysis into Matlab

Tags: matlab, finite-element, data-management

I need to import in Matlab the results (like time histories of diplacement or frequency response at a specific point) obtained from a FEM analysis in Nastran.

At the moment I ask Nastran to save the results on a file .dat and then I upload this file into Matlab. The fact is that Nastran organizes the data in a way that is not easy to work with, therefore I have to manually re-organize the file before loading it in Matlab.

Is there a more fast and efficient way to do this operation?

Are there toolboxes already implemented in Matlab that are compatible with FEM software outputs?

Comment: Have you checked this: http://www.personal.psu.edu/rlc138/FePostProc/fePostProc.html ?

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it although it works only with some nastran analysis, like normal modes and frequency response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to import the data I need from Nastran to Matlab.

To do that I used Patran as post-processor.

First of all you need to plot the results you are interested in using the "Graph" option in the "Results" tab.

Once you have created all the plots you need you have to click on "Utilities" --> "Results" --> "Write XY curves to file...".

The select the plot you need to import and click on "Apply".

In the same folder where you saved your model you will find the files which contain your data. Convert it to .txt or to .dat to import them in Matlab.